# Does a non-self-signed certificate, imported into root store, require a (self-signed) issuer to also be imported into the root store?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate

> Does a non-self-signed certificate, imported into root store, require a (self-signed) issuer to also be imported into the root store?

Suppose I've a certificate `A` that is signed by another certificate `B`. Is it then sufficient to only import `A` into the root store, i.e. certificate validation stops at `A`, or should `B` also be imported into the root store for proper certificate validation?

The reason I'm asking this question, is that I've encountered different results with different products (e.g. web browser or system), and so I want to know the right way.

Comment: The browser will require the end self signed certificate to be present in trusted certificate authority otherwise it will throw error, the entire chain should be configured in the certificate store so that the client applications can ensure the the certificate is signed by known entity

Comment: I'm assuming that "root store" is a certificate store containing only completely trusted certificates. It should not require it, but it's a sufficiently rare case that software may not distinguish it. Normally having something other than a self-signed "CA" certificate in a root store is evidence of misconfiguration.

Comment: Is there any standard saying whether a certificate in the root store should be self-signed or trusted as-is? @Pras

Comment: @JamesKPolk, yes you're right. Does the standard say anything?

Comment: There is no standard for this it's entirely application specific.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, so the concept of a root store is not defined in any standard? The choice of accepting certificate `A` in the root store (without `B`) is entirely up to the application, i.e some applications may accept `A` just by virtue it's in the root store, ignoring that it isn't self-signed, while other applications require `B` also in the root store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include Cert B in truststore. As mentioned in the comments, your mileage may vary as clients, as well as servers, implement RFC differently.

In terms of rules, spec for x.509 certs is in IETF [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-71). The key information is that for SSL handshake to happen client should do a full cert chain validation, which ends up with a self-signed certificate that is in your trust store.

Your Cert is not self-signed, it is issued by a different CA (cert B). If you do not have B in your truststore, then trust chain is broken. However, again as mentioned above, it is possible that client will not validate the full cert chain.

Think of it this way. Your client is presented with Cert A, which is signed by "B". Client should verify that signature on A is fine, which means it needs (certificate of) "B". If B is a "root" CA or self-signed, its "issuer" and "subject" fields will match. And if that Cert B is in your TrustStore, you are golden.

It's the job of the server to send you a [certificate list for TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2).

> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.

There is a visual representation of certificate chain verification [here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO16297.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: So, clients will not blindly trust non-self-signed certificates in the trust store, just by virtue of the certificate being in the store?

Comment: what client should do and what it does are two separate things, hence why I said your mileage may vary.  Server may simply give you a cert with no chain whatsoever. Then your client should look up the signature and go through the chain until it reaches a self-signed one, which should be in the truststore. What I see in the wild is if you don't have the intermediate server's cert, SSL verification may fail, that's why it is good to have them in the truststore "as well" as the self-signed / root-cas (which are self signed).

Comment: Thanks, by "intermediate server's cert" you meant "server's intermediate cert", right?

Comment: I meant intermediate CA server's cert.

Comment: Thanks, but keep in mind that not all certs may correspond to a server. Certs may also correspond to a CA.